# Jackson: JsonInclude how to add Multiple JsonInclude annotation

Tags: java, jackson, annotations

how to include multiple annotations

Example I want to include something like this. One is custom another is non null? how to handle this

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = PositiveIntegerFilter.class)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant.
Your `PositiveIntegerFilter` have to handle nulls the way you want.

Comment: you gave me a spark :) negative values can be ignored from my constructor. I dont need this custom filter. Thank you!